# why Result<T,E> instead of Result<T,E: Error> in rust?

Tags: rust

I am new to rust and still trying to grab the concept of it.
In Error trait [docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/error/trait.Error.html#method.source) it mentions

> Error is a trait representing the basic expectations for error values, i.e., values of type E in Result<T, E>

But why Result is defined as `Result<T,E>` instead of `Result<T,E:Error>` to make it clearer?

Comment: Because the standard library rarely uses trait bounds on *structs*, they're usually on impl blocks, and more so because there is no reason to so restrict `Result`, it works perfectly well with things which don't implement `Error` itself.

Comment: A perfect example being [`.binary_search()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.binary_search) which returns `Result<usize, usize>`

Comment: And another example are things like [`Rc::try_unwrap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/alloc/rc/struct.Rc.html#method.try_unwrap), which consume the value, try to convert it to something else and return the original value in case of error.

Comment: There is no point in restricting the use of `Result` like that. I suspect you might be thinking too much about exceptions in some other languages.

Comment: Note that while it is true that `E` is not required to implement `Error`, the aforementioned cases are actually a design mistake (at least `try_unwrap()`). The error type should at least implement `Debug`, so that `unwrap()` and `expect()` can work. A better candidate is `Box<dyn Error>` (or other variants such as `anyhow::Error`, which is an error type but does not implement `Error`.

Comment: Another reason: in `#[no_std]` environments the `Error` trait is not available, at least for the stable version today, but `Result` is still extensively used.